# R- How to create a matrix of T/F depending if the vector contains a value

Tags: r

I am trying to make a matrix that contains TRUE(1) and FALSE(0). Currently I am using a double for loop.

```
install.packages("phytools")
library(phytools)
A1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
A2 <- c("a", "e", "f")
A3 <- c("t", "o", "x")
c(A1, A2, A3)->Test
c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "t", "o", "x")-> list

capture.output(for( i in Test){
  for( RT in list){
    print(i %in%  RT)
    x[Test, list] = i %in% RT
  }
}, file = "/Users/Users/Desktop/Test")
```

While this does somewhat work. It currently returns a list of length(test) x length(list). I can coerce this into a data matrix with

```
matrix(unlist(read.table("/Users/Users/Desktop/Test")), 
ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)-> Matrix
```

however I believe this is not accurately testing whether or not each element of "list", such as A is in each of the three vectors (A1, A2, A3)

Im not sure where im going wrong or how to directly print my double for loop into a matrix.

Comment: You don't need "phytools" for this example I don't think. Also, you haven't defined what `x` is in your double loop so your code doesn't run.

Comment: If you are trying to create a matrix whose (i, j)th element is true if Test[i] equals list[j] then `outer(Test, list, "==")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```r
A1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
A2 <- c("a", "e", "f")
A3 <- c("t", "o", "x")
Test <- list(A1=A1,A2=A2,A3=A3)

c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "t", "o", "x")-> list


lapply(Test,function(x) list %in% x) -> tmp

final.df <- cbind(list, as.data.frame(tmp))

final.df
#>   list    A1    A2    A3
#> 1    a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> 2    b  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 3    c  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 4    e FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 5    f FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 6    t FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 7    o FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 8    x FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Created on 2018-07-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Or use for loop

```r
A1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
A2 <- c("a", "e", "f")
A3 <- c("t", "o", "x")
Test <- list(A1=A1,A2=A2,A3=A3)

c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "t", "o", "x")-> list

tmp2 <- list()


for (i in 1:length(Test)){
  tmp2[[i]] <- list %in% Test[[i]]
}
 names(tmp2) <- names(Test)
final.df <- cbind(list, as.data.frame(tmp2))

final.df
#>   list    A1    A2    A3
#> 1    a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> 2    b  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 3    c  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 4    e FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 5    f FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 6    t FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 7    o FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 8    x FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Created on 2018-07-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Explanation: lapply runs `function(x){list %in% x}` for the three list and return a list.

Cool kids use `apply` instead of `for loops` in R. (You can see the code is shorter)

Comment: Worked perfectly after switching the place of the test variables and the real names. Colnames() is a bit off but thats an easy fix. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that OP has the `list` which contains unique elements across all vectors `A1`, `A2` and `A3`. And interested to know which element is present in which vector.

An option is to convert your data in `long-format` and use `table` or `reshape2::dcast` function to summarise data.

```
Test <- data.frame(A1, A2, A3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Option#1:** Using `table`

```
library(tidyverse)

Test %>% gather(key, value) %>% 
  table()

#      value
# key  a b c e f o t x
#   A1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#   A2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#   A3 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

**Option#2:** Using `reshape2::dcast`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
Test %>% gather(key, value) %>%
  dcast(value~key, fun.aggregate = function(x)length(x)>0 )

#   value    A1    A2    A3
# 1     a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2     b  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 3     c  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 4     e FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 5     f FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 6     o FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 7     t FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 8     x FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
A1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
A2 <- c("a", "e", "f")
A3 <- c("t", "o", "x")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I went with the Lapply Loop